# how to format datetime-local to DD-MM-YYYY on html or jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How can i format this Date to remove the HH:mm as it's relevant to the screen i'm building ?

```
<input id="startDate" type=datetime-local class="form-control" required>
```

Comment: Why can't you use type="date"?

Comment: i need it to take the local date to avoid it taking utc time !

Comment: can you accept my answer please?

Answer (score 0):

What about jquery masked input?
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#startDate").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"dd/mm/yyyy"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom formatter and get the date in specific format.

```
function formatDDMMYYYY(inputDate) {

    var yyyy = inputDate.getFullYear().toString();                                    
    var mm = inputDate.toLocaleString('en-us', {month:'short'});         
    var dd  = inputDate.getDate().toString();         
    dd = dd.length > 1 ? dd : "0" + dd;
    return dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
};
```